# Scala: Conditionally add element in a Map definition based on pattern match

Tags: scala, dictionary, pattern-matching

I'm trying to use Scala features as much as possible in my current project, but I have a hard time using pattern matching inside a Map definition.

To illustrate this, consider the following code snippet:

```
class Foo(val element: Option[Any], val element2: Any, ...)
val bar = new Foo(...)
val map = Map(bar.element match {
                      case None => ??? // Do not add an item here
                      case Some(el) => "element" -> el
                  }, "element2" -> element2, ...
              )
```

The issue I have in this code snippet is with the *None* case. How do I specify that no element should be added here?

I have tried several things:

- I cannot introduce a `{}` here because it would be interpreted as a `Unit`.
- Simply leaving an empty space after `case None =>` leads to a type mismatch; as it is also considered a `Unit` while we need a `Tuple2`.
- I can perform pattern matching *after* the `Map` definition, only adding an element in case of `Some(el)`. However, this does not feel like a very elegant way to do this.
- I can leave out the `case None =>` altogether, but this generates a warning, as the match is not exhaustive, and fails if the element is indeed `None`.

If I wanted to cover all the cases inside the Map definition, how can I indicate that in case of `None`, no element should be added?

Some context: I'm using this as part of the (akka) spray json protocol definition for a certain type, and wondered if there is a shorthand way to do this without resorting to conditionally adding elements to a map.

Thanks in advance!

### **Edit: suggested solution**

Based on the answer of [mavarazy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/575338/mavarazy), I have solved this issue by code that looks something like this:

```
class Foo(val element: Option[Any], val element2: Any, ...)
val bar = new Foo(...)
val map = Map(bar.element match {
                      case None => "" -> null // Do not add an item here
                      case Some(el) => "element" -> el
                  }, "element2" -> element2, ...
              ).filter(_._2 != null)
```

Never thought of doing it that way, but I think it is still somewhat elegant. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with option 3 from my point of view, but If you don't like it, you can also do something like this:

```
val map = Map(
  "element" -> element,
  "element2" -> Option(element2)
).
  filter(_._2.isDefined).
  mapValues(_.get)
```

It will also prevent you from `Map` with `null` values in `element2`, if this is one of your concerns.

Comment: This did the trick for me. I can incorporate it as part of the 4th option. However, I used a slightly different scheme - in case of `None`, I add `"" -> null` and filter it out. Never thought of doing it that way. Thanks! I would upvote if my reputation would allow it.

Comment: This is fine, but in Scala you should avoid using null, and prefer Option. This is also true for Java8, where there is a separate Option class, which you should use in return statements, in case of nullable values

Answer (score 1):

On option 3 you can remove the None case, by replacing .map by .collect which receives a partial function

Answer (score 0):

Using the 'collect' would be my preference since it takes a partial function i.e. only collects those values that match the patterns specified in the partial function -

```
val map: Map[String, Option[String]] = Map(
  "element" -> Some("element"),
  "element2" -> Some("element2"),
  "element3" -> None
)
map collect { case (s, Some(e)) => (s, e) }
```